# Calling a function for two geojson files in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, popup, function

I have two geojson files :

1- world_countries.geojson : each feature has properties "name" and "relation" as in the following example:

```
{ 
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "France",
        "relation":{
          "Algeria": "Colony",
          "Spain" : "EU",
        }
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

2- African_countries.geojson  :

```
{ 
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
           "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                 "name": "Algeria",
                 "Population" : "30M",
                 "Capital" : "Alger",
            }
        },
   "geometry": {
    "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": []
    }
  }
]
}
```

Now when clicking on an african country (algeria) and other country (France) i need windows to show up with a message "Relation between Algeria and France is : Colony".

Comment: Is that the actual content of your geojson files? Because that's not formatted according to the geojson standard.

Comment: See changes i don't know how to insert the code

Comment: Seeing a bit of the first geojson file helps (a lot), but a bit of the second one would also help. Please read https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/formatting on how to format code properly. The clearer your question looks, the easier it is for everyone else to read, understand, and answer.

Comment: OK, that's clearer. Now: *what's the problem you're stuck with*?

Comment: Now i want to know the relationship between two countries when clicking on them both as in the example i want a window or an alert mesage saying "Relationship between Algeria and France is : Colony"

Comment: So you already have some basic display and interaction working, right? How does that look like? What are the names of the variables in which you hold the layers being displayed in the map? What happens in your current code when you click on two countries?

Comment: I have two variables : worldcountries and africancountries i can only diplay them on a map (actually i can make popups on clicking a countrie to display infos) but what i want is a function that takes two variables wich thier values are given when clicking on tow countries